# Python Rational Class __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through the Rational class and trying to learn the in's and out's. I want my `__init__` function to be able to accept (int), (Rational, Rational), (Rational, int), (int, Rational), and (int, int) as parameters but I don't know how to make it do that. Any advice, suggestions, or revision for what I already have?

```
class Rational(object):

    def __init__(self,numerator=0,denominator=1):

        '''Constructor for Rational'''
        if denominator==0:
            return 'Denominator cannot be zero.'
        else:
            self.n=numerator
            self.d=denominator
            return
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of return you want to `raise ZeroDivisionError("Division by 0")`

Now already your code accepts Rationals; however you might want to have a special handling for them. You can use `isinstance` in if:

```
if isinstance(n, Rational):
    # ok n is not an int but a rational number...
```

and then recompute `n` and `d`

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to keep `numerator` and `denominator` as `int`, so if one or both of them are not int, convert them to int e.g. `1,2/3` shall lead to `3,2`.

Python already have rationals but are named [fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) though are deriveed from abstract class `numbers.Rational`, you can see the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py) for enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isinstance`.
Here is one possible implementation:

```
def __init__(self,numerator=0,denominator=1):
    if isinstance(numerator,int) and isinstance(denominator,int):
        self.n = numerator
        self.d = denominator
    else:
        if isinstance(numerator,int):
            numerator = Rational(numerator)
        if isinstance(denominator,int):
            denominator = Rational(denominator)
        self.n = numerator.n*denominator.d
        self.d = numerator.d*denominator.n
    if self.d==0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError()
```